# Java: Setting a variable to a variable of a class, where the name of the class is a string?

Tags: java, string, class, variables

This is my third (and hopefully final) question today.

Is it possible to declare the value of a variable to the variable of a class, where the name of the class is a string?

Example

```
int newalpha;
String color_name = "yellow";
Color red = new Color();
Color yellow = new Color();
Color blue = new Color();
newalpha = color_name.alpha
```

In this example, ".alpha" is a variable contained inside of the Color class. The part I'm wanting to simulate is the "newalpha = color_name.alpha", because obviously "color_name" is a String, not a color. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR answer: no.

<strike>Reality: yes, sort of, via reflection, and ew.</strike>

Depending on your use case, there may be a way to achieve what you want, like by storing the colors in a hash map with the color names as the keys, so you'd just say `colors.get(colorName).alpha`.

```
Map<String, Color> colors = new HashMap<String, Color>() {{
    put("red", new Color());
    put("yellow", new Color());
    put("blue", new Color());
}};
String colorName = "yellow";
int newalpha = colors.get(colorName).alpha;
```

Comment: It's actually *not possible* -- without even a "sort of" -- in this case because they are local variables and not class members ;-) In any case, consider expanding the example (using HashMap or whatnot).

Comment: Typo with the type parameters: Map<Color> --> Map<String, Color> ;)

Answer (score 0):

As posted elsewhere, the answer to your exact question is, "No." And my addition: "Use a more expressive language, like Lisp, Python, Ruby, or one like them."

I suspect that you're asking the wrong question though. What you really want is a way to get the alpha value of an arbitrary color. The object-oriented design advocate would use this as an opportunity to fill your head with factory methods, subtype polymorphism, enumerated types, and other such things.

Given my completely-uneducated guesstimate about your level of coding and the complexity of the project, it looks like an acceptable workaround (if not The Right Way) is a lot simpler:

```
int newAlpha = 0;
if(colorName.equals("yellow") newAlpha = yellow.getAlpha();
else if(colorName.equals("red") newAlpha = red.getAlpha();
else if(colorName.equals("blue") newAlpha = blue.getAlpha();
else //raise some kind of exception, assert false, or do something else that seems sensible
```

(Note that I've slightly changed a few names to match Java's style.)

I have no idea what's going on in the `Color` class (or even how `red`, `yellow`, and `blue` are different--with the current code they'll be the same thing (local variable names do not affect the object they refer to)), but it's probably appropriate to break the if-sequence into a separate method. And/or use a `HashMap` thus:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> alphaValues = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
alphaValues.put("red", /* something like red.getAlpha() */);
//etc.
// ...
newAlpha = alphaValues.get(colorName);
```

I haven't really addressed the scope issue--I'm sure you can figure it out.

Hope that helps!

*Edit: Dave Newton beat me to the punch about the hashmap--he edited his post while I was creating mine.*

Comment: This would get no love in most of the "expressive" languages either. For the general sense a map *is* the appropriate structure -- some languages just support the idiom (or that of a nice "case expression") better.